# Ladder Operations and Rodriguez formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, mathematics

During my attempt to prove the Rodriguez Formula for Hermite Polynomials by using the Ladder Operators,
$H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}$, I arrived to the formula $H_n(x) =  e^{x^2/2}(-\frac{d}{dx}+x)^ne^{-x^2/2}$.Where $(-\frac{d}{dx}+x)^n$ represents the operator being applied n times. Now I have no idea on how to prove these two to be equivalent. Any hints or solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it might help to consider the commutator: $[-\frac{d}{dx}, e^{-x^2/2}]$ and thereby show that $[\left(-\frac{d}{dx} + x\right), e^{-x^2/2}] = -2e^{-x^2/2}\frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: But, might be better to ask think on the math stack exchange...

Comment: Do you appreciate what happens for *n* =1 ?

Comment: [On the math site](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4744101/362193).